# Visual Studio Performance Analyze on deployed project

Tags: .net, performance, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, analyzer

I really like the Visual Studio Performance Tools.
But is there any way to use those tools on a system without visual studio installed.
For example, let the tool run on that system and let it collect data which can later
be imported into visual studio. Something like that?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install on a remote system VS Standalone Profiler and use its command line.

There is a section in MSDN that describes how to do that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182401(v=vs.110).aspx.